# mocking a successful update test case with mongo DB and GO

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to an `UpdateOne` in my testcase so that the `ModifiedCount` is at least 1. Example:

```
if !(res.ModifiedCount > 0) {

    return ErrUpdateCourse
}
```

---

error

```
    Error:          Target error should be in err chain:
                    expected: ""
                    in chain: "error occurred in UpdateCourse while updating record"
    Test:           TestCourseRepo_UpdateCourse
```

---

Method being tested

```
func (r *CourseRepo) UpdateCourse(ctx context.Context, c *Course) error {
    clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(ctx)

    objID, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(c.Id)
    if err != nil {
        clog.ErrorCtx(err, log.Ctx{"msg": "error occurred in UpdateCourse while converting object key to hex"})

        return ErrConvertingKeyToHex
    }

    filter := bson.D{
        {"_id", objID},
    }

    update := bson.D{
        {"$set", bson.D{
            {"title", c.Title},
            {"description", c.Description},
            {"lessons", c.Lessons},
            {"duration", c.Duration},
        }},
    }

    res, err := r.collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        clog.ErrorCtx(err, log.Ctx{"msg": "error occurred in UpdateCourse while updating record"})

        return ErrUpdateCourse
    }

    if !(res.ModifiedCount > 0) {

        return ErrUpdateCourse
    }

    return nil
}
```

---

```
func TestCourseRepo_UpdateCourse(t *testing.T) {
    mt := mtest.New(t, mtest.NewOptions().ClientType(mtest.Mock))
    defer mt.Close()

    ctx := context.Background()

    testCases := []struct {
        name         string
        course       *Course
        mockResponse bson.D
        expected     int
        err          error
    }{
        {
            name: "Update Course Successful",
            course: &Course{
                Id:          primitive.NewObjectID().Hex(),
                Title:       "I am a old title",
                Description: "test",
                Lessons:     "3",
                Duration:    "5 hours",
            },
            mockResponse: bson.D{
                {"ok", 1},
                {"value", bson.D{
                    {"title", "Test Successful"},
                    {"description", "This is a sample course"},
                    {"lessons", "10"},
                    {"duration", "2 weeks"},
                    {"topic", "Test"},
                    {"subscription", true},
                },
                },
            },
            err: nil,
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range testCases {
        tc := tc
        mt.Run(tc.name, func(mt *mtest.T) {
            mt.AddMockResponses(mtest.CreateCursorResponse(1, "mock.course",
                mtest.FirstBatch, tc.mockResponse))

            repo := NewCourseRepository(mt.Client, mt.Coll)

            err := repo.UpdateCourse(ctx, tc.course)
            assert.ErrorIs(t, err, tc.err)
        })
    }
}
```